# Word that takes the most hits on one button in a row on a cell phone

Tags: spelling, curiosity

It's a silly question but I'm wondering which German word requires the most hits on one button on a (cell) phone key pad (not a smart phone obviously).

I found "versprechen" which has 4.

> v e r s p r e c h e n
>   8 3 7 7 7 7 3 2 4 3 6

Not sure if more is possible but you never know. Compounds are welcome, too, but they need to make at least some sense... so just things people might actually come up with in conversation. No names.

Comment: _Kaffeefeder_ has 8. Or were the words supposed to make sense?

Comment: @chirlu... yes :). But I think you got something to work with right there

Comment: Aha, T9. Und wenn man ohne T9 schreibt, wie ich? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bei einer Suche mit

```
 egrep -i "[mno]{6,}" utf-german
```

finde ich als Endergebnis:

> Monomorphismen Monomorphismus

nach vielen Treffern mit 5 Zeichen:

```
egrep -i "[def]{5,}" utf-german
```

> Auslöseeffekt Endeffekt Gänsefeder Gänsefedern Haltefeder
>   Hardwaredefekt
>   Hardwaredefekte
>   Hardwaredefekts
>   Kaffeeernte
>   Kaffeeernten
>   Kaffeeexport
>   Kaffeeexporte
>   Linefeed
>   Pfeffer
>   Pfefferkorn
>   Pfefferminz
>   Pfefferminze
>   Pfeffers
>   gepfeffert
>   gepfefferte
>   gepfeffertem
>   gepfefferten
>   gepfefferter
>   gepfeffertes
>   pfeffere
>   pfeffern
>   pfeffernd
>   pfeffernde
>   pfefferndem
>   pfeffernden
>   pfeffernder
>   pfefferndes
>   pfefferst
>   pfeffert
>   pfefferte
>   pfefferten
>   pfeffertest
>   pfeffertet
>   ungefedert
>   ungefederte
>   ungefedertem
>   ungefederten
>   ungefederter
>   ungefedertes

und einer Suche nach kürzeren Folgen mit abc:

```
 egrep -i "[abc]{4,}" utf-german
```

> Abbau Abbaubarkeit Abbaubarkeiten Abbaufortschritt Abbaufortschritts
>   Abbaufortschrittsmessung Abbaufront Abbaugerät Abbaugeräusche
>   Abbauleistung Abbauleitzentrale Abbauleitzentralen Abbaumaschine
>   Abbaumaschinen Abbaumaterial Abbaumaterials Abbaumenge Abbaumengen
>   Abbaumöglichkeit Abbaumöglichkeiten Abbaus Abbausituation
>   Abbausituationen Abbausysteme Abbausystemen Abbauwerkzeug
>   Abbauwerkzeuge Abbauwerkzeugen Abbauwerkzeuges Abbauwerkzeugs
>   Beamtenabbau Cabaret Handhabbarkeit Kaaba Kohleabbaus Kostenabbau
>   Lagerabbau Leistungsabbau Lohnabbau Lohnabbaus Personalabbau
>   Preisabbau Sabbat Sabbats Sabbatschändung Sabbatschändungen
>   Stabbatterie Stabbatterien abband abbanden abbandest abbandet abbandst
>   abbat abbaten abbatest abbatet abbatst abbaubar abbaubare abbaubarem
>   abbaubaren abbaubarer abbaubares abbaue abbauen abbauend abbauende
>   abbauendem abbauenden abbauender abbauendes abbaust abbaut abbaute
>   abbauten abbautest abbautet handhabbar handhabbare handhabbarem
>   handhabbaren handhabbarer handhabbares

Mit anderen Wörterbüchern sind natürlich spektakulärere Ergebnisse denkbar.

Randnotiz zu egrep/grep. Egrep ist die ***e***xtended Form von grep. Der Schalter -i verlangt eine *case **i**nsensitive* Suche. "[mno]{6,}" verlangt, dass beliebige Zeichen der Gruppe (mno) 6 mal oder mehr vorkommen müssen und *utf-german* ist der Name der Wörterbuchdatei in der gesucht werden soll. Grep/egrep sind Standardprogramme bei Unix/Linux, aber auch für Windowssysteme frei verfügbar.

Comment: _Monomorphismus_ is super; daraus lassen sich auch noch längere m/n/o-Folgen bauen, zumindest _Gruppenmonomorphismus_ und _Vektorraummonomorphismus_ (jeweils 7) werden tatsächlich verwendet. Wenn man eine spezielle Art vielleicht nach dem Ort _Heilbronnmonomorphismus_ nennen würde, hätte man sogar 9. ;-) _Monommonomorphismus_ wäre auch nicht undenkbar.

Comment: Ja, man könnte 3 Kategorien bilden, Wörter, die man wirklich im Wöterbuch gefunden hat, Wörter, die man zusammengebaut hat und die noch von der Community akzeptiert werden - Heilbronn~ oder Hormonmonomorphismus vielleicht, während ich Monomonomorphismus ablehene (wieso dann nciht 3 Monos vorneweg oder 42?), und Wörter die man unabhängig in der Wildnnis gefunden hat und für vor der Fragestellung geschrieben belegen kann. Aber Monomonomorphismus lehne ich als Nonomonomorphismus ab. ;)

Comment: Nicht _Monomonomorphismus_, sondern _Monommonomorphismus_, ein Monomorphismus, der auf Monomen operiert. ;-) Aber die Kaffeefee mit ihrer _Kaffeefeefederboa_ hat auch 11 und gefällt mir gerade besser.

Comment: Ah, das war meinem Auge zu monomorph, das hat ein m einfach überhüpft.